# WooCommerce REST API not returning the default products category

Tags: categories, woocommerce-offtopic, rest-api

I am trying to get all the categories of products through Woocommerce REST API. I am using `https://www.georgiaphonecase.com/wp-json/wc/v3/products/catagories` this path to fetch the categories. It is returning all the categories but the default one.

Can anyone please give me any solution. I could not fetch products of that certain category without knowing it's it.

Comment: Is the default category empty?

Comment: No, it has 44 values